# Unable to find element and send keys

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, appium

So just a brief overview, I'm unable to send keys to a edit text field for android. I've successfully sent keys to this element via browser but in order to test the mobile application fully, I'd like to run e2e tests on a device using Appium.

I've successfully got Appium to click button elements but am having a hard time getting it to send keys to an edit field element.

Am I able to find elements by model when testing with android as I have set in my forgot-pin-page.js?

> pin-reset-page.js

```
var pinResetPage = function() {
    describe('The Reset Pin Flow', function () {

            forgotPinPage = forgotPinPageBuilder.getForgotPinPage(),

        describe('The Forgot Pin Page', function () {

            it('should allow the user to enter their MSISDN and continue',
                function () {
                    forgotPinPage.enterMsisdn('123123123');
                    forgotPinPage.doForgotPin();
                    expect(securityPage.isOnSecurityPage()).toBe(true);
                });
        });

}
```

> forgot-pin-page.js

```
  'use strict';
var ForgotPin = function () {
    var forgotPinPageContent = element(by.id('forgot')),
        msisdnInput = element(by.model('data.msisdn')),
    return {


          enterMsisdn: function (msisdn) {
                return msisdnInput.sendKeys(msisdn);
            }

};
module.exports.getForgotPinPage = function () {
    return new ForgotPin();
};
```

The error i'm getting is

```
     ? should allow the user to enter their MSISDN and continue
            - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout spe
cified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Comment: Why are you returning a value in the constructor? Is enterMsisdn() a page object function?

Comment: Yes enterMsisdn is a page object function

Comment: I've actually figured it out, well part of it. It seems as if protractor is only running one unit test then will timeout before it can get to the next one.

Comment: Since you're having issues with the timeout, can you check and make sure that it has a proper beforeeach/aftereach? It has to be set up right, of course. If it is an actual timeout problem, you can add these to your conf.js file: `browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(25000);` `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);` `allScriptsTimeout: 15000`

See if these help at all

Comment: I was able to resolve to issue by downgrading to jasmine instead of jasmine2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct solution but it worked for me. I downgraded jasmine2 to jasmine and that seemed to resolved the async timeouts I was having.